# Acid strengths for HBrO4 vs HIO4, and HBr vs HI

Tags: acid-base

So I was looking at [factors that control the relative strengths of acids and bases](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch11/factors.php).

We know that $\ce{HI}$ is a stronger acid that $\ce{HBr}$ because $\ce{I}$ is a much larger atom.

But then, I read somewhere that $\ce{HBrO4}$ is stronger than $\ce{HIO4}$, because in this case it's electronegativity that plays the important role.

How do you know whether to use size or EN as a guideline for comparing strengths of acids/bases?

Comment: In HI and HBr, the hydrogen is directly bonded to the halogen, but in the perhalic acids it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "We know that HI is a stronger acid that HBr because I is a much larger atom"

That is only half the story. It is about the strength of the H-Br versus H-I bond. Since I is larger than Br, the H-I bond is longer, weaker, and therefore more prone to dissociation. See [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13609/hydrogen-halide-acidity) for more in-depth discussion.

> $\ce{HBrO4}$ and $\ce{HIO4}$

both have the acidic proton bound to oxygen:

[image]

The H-O bond is approximately of equal strength in both acids and therefore you turn to electronegativity arguments.