# Solubility vs Dissociation of HF

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solubility

Ok, so I understand that solubility is a measure of how well a compound is solvated by the solvent. And dissociation is a measure of how much of a compound splits into its ionized forms.
**Does HF have high solubility, but low dissociation (weak acid)? How can that be?**

Is it because it forms strong hydrogen bonds in solution and thus forms stable solvation spheres (solubility), but its high electronegativity prevents H+ atoms from leaving its vicinity (dissociation)?

Comment: Solubility and dissociation are totally unrelated things, like bulimia and amnesia. Sugar (or better yet, ethanol) dissolves extremely well, but does not dissociate at all. $\ce{AgCl}$ is an example of the opposite kind.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - For chemicals which are considered to be ionic compounds solubility and dissociation are somewhat linked.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, somewhat. BTW, would you consider $\ce{HF}$ ionic? To me, it isn't (that is, unless dissolved in water, but even then, not quite).

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/why-is-hf-the-least-acidic-hydrogen-halide

Answer (score 1):

I think your last sentence answers your own question very well:

> It is because it forms strong hydrogen bonds in solution and thus forms
>   stable solvation spheres (solubility), but its high electronegativity
>   prevents $\ce{H+}$ atoms from leaving its vicinity (dissociation).

Dissociation is one mechanism of dissolution, but not the only one. Also, however, the $\ce{H-F}$ bond strength is not solely determined by electronegativity.

Comment: Agreed. Dissociation, and (in most cases) the resulting formation of separated charge pairs, is an important mechanism of solubility for many ionic species in polar solvents.

Comment: Electronegativity is one thing, but bond strengths are also important to consider: see for example http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13609/hydrogen-halide-acidity

Comment: @orthocresol, very good point. I kind of lumped bond strength with the difference in electronegativities of H and F in my mind, which isn't right. I made a slight edit to at least address that. Maybe not enough so, but for this specific question I hope that's sufficient.